# How to create model class and how to use with sections in tableview

Tags: ios, swift

JSON Response:

How to map that model classes to Array and how to display them in Table. I am new to swift please help me in this.

This data of departments will receive from my JSON response

```
{
 "content" :
 [
  {
"Agriculture" :             
  [
    {
        "displayName" : "Agri e-Permit",
        "downloads" : 3
    },
    {
        "displayName" : "Shri test",
        "downloads" : 1
    }
  ]
},
{
"Education" :             
   [
    {
        "displayName" : "apple cat",
        "downloads" : 1
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

My issue is how to create a data model and how to assign values and how to use it in tableView with sections in ViewController is my issue.

*** Here The departments "Agriculture", "Education" and "Municipality" ........ more. It's not constant. we have to take the first index of that array for the department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with some basic Structs for our parsed objects. These can later be used to populate our UITableView.

```
struct Section {
    let name: String
    let rows: [Row]
}

struct Row {
    let displayName: String
    let downloads: Int
}
```

Next lets create some sections from your JSON. The code below is unsafe (lots of `!` and is also quite verbose), but should hopefully help explain what you need to do:

```
// This will hold our final sections for populating the table view
var sections = [Section]()

// This is test code for loading a json file from disk - assume you will get yours from a network call
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Data", withExtension: ".json")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)

// This converts the Data object to a Swift Dictionary that we can now use to create our sections
let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

// Each section dictionary is in an array within the json "content"
let contentArray = dict["content"] as! [[String: Any]]

// Loop all section dictionaries in the array.
for sectionDictionary in contentArray {

    // Then enumerate inside that dictionary to get the section contents.
    for (sectionKey, sectionValue) in sectionDictionary {

        // Check we have another array of dictionaries as our value, otherwise bail out.
        guard let rowsArray = sectionValue as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

        // Use compactMap to build our rows.
        let rows: [Row] = rowsArray.compactMap { rowDict in
            // Check we have a valid row otherwise bail out.
            guard let displayName = rowDict["displayName"] as? String, let downloads = rowDict["downloads"] as? Int else { return nil }
            return Row(displayName: displayName, downloads: downloads)
        }

        let section = Section(name: sectionKey, rows: rows)
        sections.append(section)
    }
}
```

You should then have a populated array (`sections`) ready to use in your table.